# overflow-wrap difference between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

The following HTML/CSS seems to display differently between Chrome and Firefox.  On Chrome, "Hello world" is broken like "He
llo world", while on Firefox, "Hello world" appears together on the next line.  Is this a bug in one of the browsers?  Or is either rendering permissible?

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  width: 350px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.f {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 110px;
  height: 16px;
  background: black;
}

.fl {
  float: left;
}

.fr {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>
    <span class="f fl"></span><span class="f fl"></span>
    <span class="f fr"></span><span class="f fr"></span>
  </p>
  <p>
    Hello world
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: The relevant sentence from the spec for overflow-wrap is "An otherwise unbreakable sequence of characters may be broken at an arbitrary point if there are no otherwise-acceptable break points in the line.". The use of the word "may" here suggests that either implementation is valid.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me :

Sorry for my coding style... Just a quick message.

```
<div class="container">
  <p>
    <span class="f fl"></span><span class="f fl"></span>
    <span class="f fr"></span><span class="f fr"></span>
  </p>
  <p style="display:inline-block;margin:0px;padding:0px;">
    Hello world
  </p>
</div>
```